# How to get total acceleration value from accelerometer(mpu 9150)

Tags: physics, acceleration

I have the value of acceleration in all 3-axis ax,ay,az in unit g. I need the magnitude of total acceleration, so that I used the formula, 
max_acc= sqrt(ax^2+ ay^2 + az^2) 
My question is, is my approach correct or not? 
If it is not correct, your any kind of suggestion will be a great help.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your formula correctly calculates the magnitude of total acceleration for a sample from the accelerometer. It seems a bit unclear what you mean by 'maximum'.

Comment: @sallinen, actually I meant 'maximum acceleration in a certain time period'. Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct.

If you just want to have translational acceleration without gravity, you have to subtract the gravity first.

If your accelerometer for example is positioned in a way, that gravity is aligned with ay
you have to calculate:
acc = sqrt(ax^2 + (ay-g)^2 + az^2)